# Help understanding sed command

Tags: sed

Can anyone help me understand what this sed command does :

```
sed -n '/\(^[^:]*[eE]xception\):.*/s//\1/p' $LOGFILE | uniq -c
```

Does this search `$LOGFILE` for the words `Exception` or `exception`, count how many lines have this word and report the count?

I know that `-n` means suppress output, and `uniq -c` reports the number of matches but I do not understand what the `'/\(^[^:]*[eE]xception\):.*/s//\1/p'` is doing.

Many thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of strange things here. First, as I just learned trying to answer your question (thanks!), `sed` has a cool trick:

```
/foo/s//bar/
```

This means "if this line matches `foo`, then replace whatever was matched by `foo` with `bar`. I don't really understand the point of it, to be honest, you could do the same thing with a simple `s/foo/bar/`, but there you go.

As for the regex:

- `^` : match the beginning of the line.
- `[^:]*` : when the `^` is inside square brackets, that is a negative character set. So, while `[abc]` means `a` or `b` or `c`, `[^abc]` means anything *except* `a`, `b` or `c`. So, `[^:]*` will match 0 or more non-`:`.
- `[eE]xception`: this matches `exception` or `Exception`.
- `:.*` : matches a `:` and then everything else until the end of the line.
- Finally, the first part is in escaped parentheses (`\( \)`) which means that whatever was matched is captured and can be referred to later as `\1`.

The next bit is the substitution operator, here `s//\1/p`. This means substitute whatever was matched before (including the non-captured part, so the whole line) with whatever was captured (`\1`). The result is that only whatever was on the line up to and including the word `expression` (or `Expression`) will be printed. And, since the `-n` suppresses output, the `p` at the end means "print this line if the substitution was successful.

Finally, the `uniq -c` will give you the number of lines matching the pattern found in your file. note that it is not the number of times the word `exception` occurs in the file. If you have more than one `exception:` on the same line, that will be counted as one.

Comment: There's not much point to `/foo/s//bar/`, but it's a consequence of another feature of sed - if [a search pattern is empty](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses), it reuses the last pattern. Vim also does this. In this case, I think it's a side effect of how the command was created - the author probably experimented with simple matching and then just added in a substitute command.